# What is the difference between two "state" option values, "present" and "installed", available in Ansible's yum module?

Tags: centos, ansible, yum, epel

I have the following task in my ansible playbook:

```
- name: Install EPEL repo.
  yum:
    name: "{{ epel_repo_url }}"
    state: present
    register: result
    until: '"failed" not in result'
    retries: 5
    delay: 10
```

Another value I can pass to state is "installed".  What is the difference between the two? Some documentation available here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/yum_module.html

Answer (score 24, accepted):

They do the same thing, i.e. they are aliases to each other, see this comment in the source code of the yum module:

`# removed==absent, installed==present, these are accepted as aliases`

And how they are used in the code:

```
if state in ['installed', 'present']:
    if disable_gpg_check:
        yum_basecmd.append('--nogpgcheck')
    res = install(module, pkgs, repoq, yum_basecmd, conf_file, en_repos, dis_repos)
elif state in ['removed', 'absent']:
    res = remove(module, pkgs, repoq, yum_basecmd, conf_file, en_repos, dis_repos)
elif state == 'latest':
    if disable_gpg_check:
        yum_basecmd.append('--nogpgcheck')
    res = latest(module, pkgs, repoq, yum_basecmd, conf_file, en_repos, dis_repos)
else:
    # should be caught by AnsibleModule argument_spec
    module.fail_json(msg="we should never get here unless this all"
            " failed", changed=False, results='', errors='unexpected state')

return res
```

https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/blob/devel/packaging/os/yum.py

Answer (score 24):

State as '**Present**' and '**Installed**' are used interchangeably. They both do the same thing i.e. it will ensure that a desired package in your case 'yum' is installed.

Whereas State as '**Latest**' means in addition to installation, it will go ahead and update if it is not of the latest available version.

Whenever you are building your stack/app or working on production, it is always advisable to use '**Present**' or '**Installed**' state. This is because a software update, whether it’s your app’s deploy, or a dependency version bump, it has nothing to do with server configuration, and could really break your production.

You can read and understand more about it [here](https://max.engineer/six-ansible-practices#separate-your-setup-and-deploy-playbooks).

Answer (score 5):

In 2.x `installed` and `removed` are deprecated in favor of `present` and `absent` and no longer available after Ansible 2.9